# How to get share dialog box with parse.com and facebook 3.0 sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, share, parse-platform

I can't seem to find information on how to open share dialog box with parse sdk which includes fb 3.0.  I am able to login with facebook and actually found a way to post with out the dialog box but still would like to have the dialog box so that people can add comments and it comes out with the image on facebook.  This is what i have so far.
@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions" allows me to publish with out the dialog box

```
 logInController.facebookPermissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me",@"friends_about_me",@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions", nil];
```

this is to publish

```
PF_FBRequest *request = [PF_FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:[self.Excerpt objectForKey:@"text"]];
                [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(PF_FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
                    NSLog(@"error %@",error);

                }];
```

I found the code to open the dialog box from facebook website but i am not sure how to get an instance of the PF_Facebook object so i can open the dialog box.  I can try to do

```
PF_Facebook *fb = [[PF_Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:<#(NSString *)#> andDelegate:<#(id<PF_FBSessionDelegate>)#>;
```

but that doesn't seem to be right because i already initialize this in the appdelegate

//Update
I am able to get the dialog box using this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                                   @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                   @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                                   @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];
    //publishes text on facebook
    PF_FBSession *session = [PFFacebookUtils session];

    PF_Facebook *fb = [[PF_Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:session.appID andDelegate:nil];
    [fb dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But the problem is that the person gets the login page in the dialog box even though he is authenticated already in the app

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

To set up a `PF_Facebook` object you need to also provide the access token and expiration date information as below:

```
PF_FBSession *session = [PFFacebookUtils session];  
PF_Facebook *facebook = [[PF_Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:session.appID 
                                               andDelegate:nil];

// Store the Facebook session information
facebook.accessToken = session.accessToken;
facebook.expirationDate = session.expirationDate;
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than creating a new session, you can just use the "facebook" class method to get a configured PF_Facebook object

```
    PF_Facebook *facebook = [PFFacebookUtils facebook];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Check out this great app", @"message", nil]:

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:parameters andDelegate:nil];
```

Comment: Is this still working for you guys? i find that no matter what state the session & permissions are in, i end up getting asked to re-login through the Request Dialog. With Marcus' approach I can avoid the prompt, but I end up with an "Error 10", "The access token was not obtained using single sign-on". I'm using v1.1.29 of the Parse API.